# Detecting ball moving between IR pair and handling ambient light changes

Tags: arduino, infrared

I plan to use the [SEN-00241](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/241) IR Emitter and Detector pair to detect a ping pong ball moving fast between them.

I understand I could watch for voltage changes to detect this passing object, however how do people generally deal with ambient light changes? From my research it seems that the voltage will change with ambient light, and although I can take steps to create funnel vision between the 2 I'm sure it may still be an issue.

Would you take constant readings and find averages over 10 consecutive readings to allow for changes in ambient light and set a new baseline reading? Then if the voltage changes dramatically and only for a few reads then I know that was the ball and not to change the baseline reading.

Comment: Cross post with: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/detecting-ball-moving-between-ir-pair-and-handling-ambient-light-changes

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is perfectly sound, and assuming nothing goes wrong should work very well.

Another possibility is a narrowband filter at 940 nm, which will filter out most stray light. At this time, eBay has such a filter, about the right size, for less than $20.

Comment: Great idea, I will look into that if the tunneling doesn't reduce enough light. Thanks!